# Get all records created today in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I want to get all the records from the database which are create_at today. But when I do

```
Model.where('DATE(created_at) = ?',Date.today)
```

it returns only the last record that is created today. I have 3 records with created_at

```
2015-03-03 11:38:31
2015-03-03 11:59:00
2015-03-03 11:33:04
```

. But it returns only the record with '2015-03-03 11:38:31' this created_at date.

Also referred [How to delete all records created today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864735/how-to-delete-all-records-created-today), [Getting all rows created today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871800/getting-all-rows-created-today). I want to know why is this happening? 
Also tried

```
 Model.where("DATE(created_at) = ?",Date.today)
```

and

```
 Tracking::TrackingLogin.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Please someone explain what is happening in my code?

Comment: `Model.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)`

Comment: if you are using `mysql` `Model.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today)` this should also work

Comment: Can you please tell us, which database you are using?

Comment: I am using MySql database

Comment: Check what you get when you print `DATE(created_at)` and `Date.today` their format and does it trying to match exact time when you are doing `Model.where("DATE(created_at) = ?",Date.today)`. Try putting hardcoded timestamps `2015-03-03 11:59:00` and see if it returns the record.

Answer (score 12):

Try the following:

```
Model.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Model.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)

Model = your model name

(i.e,. User.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day))

Comment: This answer could use some clarity and formatting

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score -1):

```
Model.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today)
```

Comment: This also returns only the first record. Not all the records.

Comment: this isn't right. Date.today comes without timezone information,   sql plan  will looks like =>   SELECT "modes".* FROM "modes" WHERE "modes"."is_deleted" = 'f' AND (created_at >= '2016-05-17')   which is queried by UTC of today.